# How to run WPF application in background using pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, ui-automation, pywinauto

How to run an application in background ? `type_keys` and `click_input` requires active window. Instead of `type_keys` and `click_input()`, is there any way to run WPF application in a background ???

Comment: What is WF? Maybe you mean WPF?

Comment: WinForms and WPF are very different from automation point of view. For WinForms it's possible to use `backend="win32"` and methods `send_chars` and `send_keystrokes` for edit controls even in minimized state. Also it's interesting how you're running automation script: on local machine or remotely? In the second case the solution is much easier: https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html

Comment: send_keystrokes('{ENTER}') is not working ....

Comment: send_keystrokes('{ENTER}') is not working after minimizing and running the WPF Application ..my scenario is to click the button..Eg:Submit button

Comment: @VasilyRyabov sir any idea?/

Comment: @VasilyRyabov  i have uninstalled python (64 bit) and added python (32 bit) and changed my backend("win32")...i want the application to be run in minimize mode.. type_keys is working fine but .click() is not working!!!

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such way for WPF. I have no time to take a deep look, sorry. But I will keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: WPF controls are totally not visible to `win32` backend. So `send_keystrokes` is useless here.

Comment: As I remember, method `.invoke()` should bring WPF app to focus that breaks your idea to have an app always minimized.

Comment: But if you're running any app on a remote machine, it's possible to disconnect RDP with keeping an active desktop: https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html